# How to force reloading iml file intellij

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, maven-3, intellij-plugin

I m using intellij 2016 , I import a java project.

Unfortunately , even i made reimport maven projet , still have problem with dependencies , i can t update the dependencies from the pom.

[image]

When i open the *.iml , it's empty no classpath was added.

[image]

and my External Libraries is empty.

[image]

How can i do to load all dependencies from the pom ? and reload the iml file.

Thxs.

Comment: Reimport all maven projects didn't work? Also, make sure you have the option Maven > Import Maven project automatically checked on preferences. Usually when I have this option unchecked I have trouble downloading the dependencies, which I believe is what is happening with you.

Comment: Yes , I had to modify the settings.xml

Answer (score 0):

I Checked the file settings.xml from the folder .m2

I had to add the repositories like this :

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>kazan-repo</id>
          <name>XXXrepository</name>
          <url>URL/</url>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
      <id>IDURL</id>
    </profile>
    <profile>
```